# openMP: Assigning specific thread to a specific core

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

Is it possible to assign a specific thread to a specific core in opeMP. If so, can anyone tell me how to do that.

I am using openMp in fortran language

Comment: This will be compiler-dependent.  What's your Fortran compiler?

Comment: That's a language version not a compiler isn't it?  Are you using GNU?

Comment: oops. Sorry. I am using Intel Fortran Compiler. I compile the fortran code using ifort

Answer (score 1):

For Intel Fortran, recent version(s) of the compiler are supposed to support this - details [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/thread-affinity-compiler-options-and-environment-variables/).

```
Version : Intel® C++ and Fortran Compilers for Windows* (versions
11.1.048 or higher) 
Intel® C++ and Fortran Compilers for Linux* (versions
11.1.056 or higher)
```