# How to make OpenMP thread or task run on a certain core

Tags: multithreading, openmp, cpu-cores

Is there a way to make an OMP thread or task run on a certain core?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428891/openmp-assigning-specific-thread-to-a-specific-core/6430141#6430141), followed the link, but I couldn't find the source code to test it. Also this is an Intel solution to it (I think). Does OMP support this itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know as of OpemMP 3.0 they're all vendor specific extensions.

For example GOMP (GCC's implementation) honours the environment variable `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` for setting thread affinity.

In their [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html) they give the example:

```
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 3 1-2 4-15:2"
```

Which they state:

> will bind the initial thread to CPU 0, the second to CPU 3, the third
>   to CPU 1, the fourth to CPU 2, the fifth to CPU 4, the sixth through
>   tenth to CPUs 6, 8, 10, 12, and 14 respectively and then start
>   assigning back from the beginning of the list. GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0
>   binds all threads to CPU 0

Comment: If I may ask, how do I set environment variables? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you normally start your program with `./myprog` you can set if for that program by starting it with `VARIABLE=value ./myprog`. You can also set it for everything started by that a given shell by using `export VARIABLE=value` (some shells might make you split the export from the setting).