# Spreading OpenMP threads among NUMA nodes

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp, numa

I have a matrix spread among four NUMA-node local memories. Now I want to open 4 threads, each one on a CPU corresponding to a different NUMA-node, so that each thread can access its part of the matrix as fast as possible. OpenMP has the "proc_bind(spread)" option, but it puts the threads on the same NUMA-node, but on far apart CPUs.

How can I force the threads to bind to different NUMA nodes?

Or, if that is not possible: When I use all cores on all nodes (256 threads total), I know how to get the ID of the NUMA node, but I can't control which thread gets which indices e.g. in a for loop. How could I distribute my workload efficiently with respect to the NUMA configuration?

Comment: There’re compiler-specific settings for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703143/126995

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I'd do:

1. Check which cores are attached to which NUMA node using `numactl -H`
2. Assuming for example cores 0, 1, 2 and 3 are each on one of the 4 NUMA nodes you want to use, set the environment variable `OMP_PLACES` to bind the threads to these cores: `export OMP_PLACES="{0},{1},{2},{3}"`
3. Finally launching your OpenMP binary with the local memory allocation policy for numactl: `numactl -l myBinary`

For what I understood of your question, that should work.